# Request Entity Too Large mod_jk

Tags: tomcat, http, httpd, apache-2.4, mod-jk

I have setup where there is apache (httpd) and apache tomcat both are connected with ajp and  in my `http.conf`

```
LimitRequestLine 65536
LimitRequestFieldSize 65536
```

under `<VirtualHost>` and outside of it as well

my `workers.properties` file looks like

```
worker.list=local
worker.local.host=127.0.0.1
worker.local.local.max_packet_size=65536
worker.local.port=9210
worker.local.reply_timeout=1800000
worker.local.type=ajp13
```

now I am making a request with cookie value > `8Kb` and I see error message on response

> Request Entity Too Large
>
> does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

I turned debug logging for mod_jk and I see

> ajp_marshal_into_msgb::jk_ajp_common.c (450): failed appending the header value for header 'Cookie' of length 6

apache access log at debug level doesn't show anything

```
ErrorLog            /some/pathapache.error.log
LogLevel            debug
```

Any one has any pointer as to what is incorrectly configured  ?

apache version `2.4.6`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key

Comment: I am actually able to pass cookie from browser to server, i verified by loggong cookie on server

Comment: Why are you using a cookie that's too large for any browser to use?

Comment: I don't have control over this cookie, it is being returned as session cookie from some SSO, @thete

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in worker.properties

```
worker.local.local.max_packet_size=65536
```

instead of

```
worker.local.max_packet_size=65536
```